# How to enable file sharing between Windows XP guest and Arch Linux host using QEMU/KVM with VirtManager?

Tags: windows, samba, qemu, shared-folders, virt-manager

I'm trying to set up a shared folder (or Samba server, but I'd prefer a shared folder) to allow file sharing between my Windows XP guest  and my host operating system. I've installed the virtio drivers but haven't been able to get it working. Can someone kindly provide guidance on how to enable file sharing and suggest any specific virtio drivers I should use?
Thank you!

Additional information:
The internet works on the windows xp guest, I seem to be able to ping the host system. The samba server I have set up was recently used to share files across my network with my windows 10 install, so that works.

Comment: The current SMB version isn't supported in Windows XP (and never will, obviously) and the only version Windows XP understands is now deprecated for security reasons. What you want to do can't be done easily. You'd need to "downgrade" the version on Arch with all the inherent risks. Furthermore you shouldn't allow any internet access to Windows XP even if only a VM.